# Fetch column values one by one from mysql using shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I have table named *student* in a *mysql* database. This table has column named *email*.

I use following command to send email to specific student, identified by *pid*:

```
$email=$(mysql --login-path=local --database=ccps -ss -e "select email from student where pid=132054");   
echo "This is sample mail" | mail -s "Test" $email
```

I want to know how to send email to each and every student in the database. As I don't know how to use loop on column *email*.

Thank You.

Comment: Using mail like this is an extremely ugly way of doing it, you really should use a scripting language that can compose full email messages, but if you're just testing then the trick is `xargs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way I can think of is:

```
for email in `mysql --login-path=local --database=ccps -ss -e "select email from student order by pid;"`
do
        echo "This is sample mail" | mail -s "Test" $email
done
```

If you haven't come across them before, the quotes just before mysql and at the end of the command are the left-handed ones, not the usual single quotes. As an earlier comment says, something like PHP would be better/easier at constructing more sophisticated emails.

Answer (score 1):

For playing around, something like this would work for you.  But there are much better ways of doing this.

```
read -ra student_emails <<< $(mysql --login-path=local --database=ccps -ss \
                                     -e "select email from student order by pid;")
for email in ${student_emails[@]}
do
    echo "This is sample mail" | mail -s "Test" ${email[0]}
done
```